# How can i make drainage density map by using drainage map

Tags: qgis, heat-map

I made drainage map, but I don't know how can make drainage density map, I just heard that I have to convert the lines into points and then use HeatMap, but I did and my results do not make sense. Who can help me to figure out it?[image]

Comment: IIUC, drainage density is total length of streams divided by total basin area. The result is a single value for the basin. What do you mean by "drainage density map"??